# calculate difference between dates..ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

My task is getting date from field in ms access database and calculate the difference of days from current date. e.g the date which i have got from db is 5/19/2014 and current date is 5/21/2014, so the answer will be:2 days.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to do the conversion in SQL or one of the .net languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `date2.Subtract(date1)` which will give you a `TimeSpan` object that contains the information you need.

Comment: Thanks buddy..it seems to be helpful.And how can i get current date using asp.net.

Comment: Again thanks a lot brother..i implemented it and it works..cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, '2010-01-22 15:29:55.090', '2010-01-22 15:30:09.153')
```